# Exporting ibmcloud github issues to CSV

Tags: python, csv, curl, github, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to export issues found in github.ibm.com, I tried many online solutions (Python scripts) but none of them is working. I tried this one as well:
https://github.com/dtoczala/IBMCloud_GitLab_CSV

but it gives me the following error:

`TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: So is your question specific to that script? What did you run, what is the call stack, ...?

Comment: No, it's not specific to this script, I tried the following as well : ```curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner>/<repo-name>/issues" -u "<user-name>" ``` but it says: " Bad credentials.. even though my credentials are correct

Comment: But you said you wanted to get issues from github.ibm.com and not github.com. They are different and have different credentials

Comment: @data_henrik Here's the exact error I get when I try to use my Name and AccessToken as credentials ```"message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.16/v3"```

Comment: I'm trying this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369365/how-can-i-export-github-issues-to-excel .. but it says not found is because it's a private repo. Also, I'm not sure whether to use http://api.ghithub or just github ?